# access first column of matrix after transpose?

Tags: r, merge, indexing, dataframe, transpose

How can I access the first column of a transposed matrix [for merging]? The column names of the transposed matrix become row names, which I somehow can't access.

Example:

I have 2 matrices:

```
mat1=data.frame(var=c('var1','var2','var3'),site1=1:3,site2=4:6)
mat2=data.frame(site=c('site1','site2'),newvar=1:2)
```

Mat 2 must be merged with mat1, so I transpose mat1:

```
mat11=t(mat1)
```

Now I have 2 matrices, of which the first columns hold the site names, and the other columns the parameters. After transpose the column header of the first column is called 'row.names'. I don't know how to access it for the merge:

> mat11[,1]

gives:    var  site1  site2 
"var1"    "1"    "4",

not the expected: row.names, var, site1, site2.

So I have no means of addressing the right column for the merge. How does this work?

Henk

Answer (score 0):

```
newvars <- as.character(mat1$var)
newnames <- names(mat1)[2:3]

mat1data <- t(mat1[,2:3])

mat11 <- data.frame(newnames, mat1data, row.names=NULL)
names(mat11) <- c("sites", newvars)

mat11

  sites var1 var2 var3
1 site1    1    2    3
2 site2    4    5    6
```